# Python Bottle not responding after 404

Tags: python, html, redirect, bottle

I'm running a Bottle v0.12.15 server which is listening on `0.0.0.0:9000`. The ip of the machine I'm running it on is `192.168.0.16`.

The only routes I have set up are to redirect anyone who connects to a static `index.html` page.

Whenever I access a random url which doesn't have a route set up from one device on my network, i.e `192.168.0.16:9000/asdf`, I consistently get an `Error: 404` as expected and can go back to the index page.

However, when accessing from 2 devices, if I land on a `404 Error` on device **1**, accessing a URL such as `192.168.0.16:9000/asdf` (which is supposed to give a 404) on device **2** just causes the Bottle server to hang and it does not give a response until I refresh the page on another device.

I tried adding an error route which gives an HTML page whenever a 404 is gotten, but the same problem persists.

I'm not sure what's causing this, or what I could do to fix it, so any help would be much appreciated.

The entirety of the runserv.py file I am running looks like this:

```
from bottle import *

#error handling


@error(404)
def error404(error):
    return static_file("404.html", 
    root="./errorFiles")

@route('/')
def slash():
    redirect("/index")

@route('')
def empty():
    redirect("/index")

@route('/index')
def index():
    return static_file("index.html", root="./webpageFiles")

run(host='0.0.0.0', port=9000, debug=True, reloader=True)
```

Comment: Does the problem go away if you remove the `@route('')`? (Which is not needed, in any case.)

Comment: Does not go away, but it at least made the code cleaner, thanks for the suggestion :)